# Mssql generate xml fragment

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
Select Ident From ObjectsToResend Where Id = 1
FOR XML PATH
```

This query generates :

```
    <row>
       <Ident>1</Ident>
    </row>
    <row>
       <Ident>2</Ident>
    </row>
```

Is it possible to generate xml fragment like this ?

```
<Ident>1</Ident>
<Ident>2</Ident>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Select Ident From ObjectsToResend Where Id = 1
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Answer (score 3):

please **do not accept this answer** as Abdul Rasheed has given a good answer already...

Just for completness, there are several ways to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @ObjectsToResend  TABLE(Ident INT, OtherColumn VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @ObjectsToResend VALUES(1,'Test 1'),(2,'Test 2');

SELECT Ident 
FROM @ObjectsToResend
FOR XML Path('')

SELECT Ident AS [*]
FROM @ObjectsToResend
FOR XML Path('Ident')

SELECT Ident AS [node()]
FROM @ObjectsToResend
FOR XML Path('Ident')

SELECT Ident + ''
FROM @ObjectsToResend
FOR XML Path('Ident')
```